# Eliminate Vertical Space in $$ $$

Tags: math-mode

Im having problems with the vertical space that the `$$ $$` command creates. For example:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2e^{-2k}}{k^2+1}\]
\item $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left|\sin{k^4}\right|}{\sqrt{k^4+1}}$$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

This creates a vertical space between the `\item` and the object in the `$$ $$` command. I just want to eliminate this effect. One possible solution is to use the fast math mode: `$object$`. But, this doesn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should not use `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX but `\[ ... \]`.
Then: you are asking for display-math which is centered. This causes the vertical space. You need inline math, i.e. use `$ ... $` or `\( ... \)` instead. You can add `\displaystyle` at the beginning to get the same style used as before:

```
\item $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left|\sin{k^4}\right|}{\sqrt{k^4+1}}$
```

Comment: Hello, your solution was exactly was I was looking for.
Thank you very much!
Now that you mentioned it, Im a little curious about why I should not use $$...$$ command...!

Comment: @user4836: Note that the correct/best answer to a question should be accepted using the tick-symbol below the vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). For the `$$` versus `\[ \]` see the question [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).